# Finding the Points of Tangency

Tags: geometry, circles

The question is as follows:

> Find the points of tangency on $x^2 + y^2 = 9$ that passes through $(10, 0)$.

I don't know which linear equation I should use for this particular problem. I know that once I make the linear equation I can substitute it back into the circle equation, but I can't figure it out! Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: From power of a point, we get that the distance from (10,0) to the point of tangency is $\sqrt{91}$.

Comment: the first equation, is thus, $(x-10)^2+y^2=91$

Comment: Secondly, tangents are always perpendicular to the radii

Comment: What's a "power of a point"?

Comment: So your second equation is $-\frac{y}{10-x}=-\frac{y}{x}$

Comment: its a collection of many little rules. search it up and look for tangent & secant

Comment: Is there any other way to do this problem? We haven't learned "power of a point" in class yet so we can't use it as a way to solve the problem.

Comment: Anyways, from solving the second equation, you should see that x=5; and thus $y = \pm \sqrt{66}$

Comment: Yes I am taking geometry.

Comment: A simple, though slightly tedious way to solve this is to write down a generic equation for a line through $(10,0)$ and then find its intersections with the circle. For the line to be tangent, there must be only a single intersection. For this particular problem, using the Pythagorean theorem is a fairly easy way to go as well.

Comment: @amd Using the generic equation for a line, how would I make sure that the line is perpendicular to the radius of the circle?

Comment: If the line has only one intersection with the circle, that’s guaranteed. You should be looking at the discriminant of the resulting quadratic equation.

Comment: Tangency points can also be found from the intersection of the given circle with the circle of center $(5,0)$ and radius $5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you’re studying geometry, here’s a geometric approach. A tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the radius drawn to the point of tangency. That gives us some right triangles to work with:

[image]

$\triangle{PAO} \sim \triangle{PBA}$, which means that $AB:OA::AP:OP$. We have $OP=10$, $OA=3$, and so $$AP=\sqrt{OP^2-OA^2}=\sqrt{10^2-3^2}=\sqrt{91}$$ and $AB={3\sqrt{91}\over10}$. Also, $$OB=OP-BP=OP-\sqrt{AP^2-AB^2}=10-\sqrt{91-\left(\frac3{10}\right)^291}=\frac9{10}.$$ However, $OB$ is just the $x$-coordinate of the points of tangency, and the $y$-coordinates are $\pm AB=\pm{3\sqrt{91}\over10}$.

For an algebraic solution, a useful concept for problems like these is that of the [polar line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar) to a point, which intersects the circle (actually, any conic) at the same points as tangents to the circle drawn from the point. The equation of the polar line of a point $(x_0,y_0)$ relative to the circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$ is exactly the same as the equation of the tangent at a point on the circle: $xx_0+yy_0=r^2$.

Using the polar line to $(10,0)$, this problem becomes one of solving the system of equations $$10x=9 \\ x^2+y^2=9$$ from which $x=\frac9{10}$ and $y=\pm{3\sqrt{91}\over10}$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of any tangent line to $x^2+y^2=9$ is $\frac{-x_0}{y_0}(x-x_0)=y-y_0.$ This is easy to calculate knowing that the slope of the line tangent to a circle at $(x_0, y_0)$ is simply perpendicular to its radius, and is thus $\frac{-x_0}{y_0}$.

Next, we simply have to solve which of those lines go through $(10, 0)$ by plugging in $(10, 0)$ for $(x, y):$
$$\frac{x_0}{\pm\sqrt{9-x_0^2}}(10-x_0)=0\pm\sqrt{9-x_0^2}\\\to
x_0(10-x_0)=9-x_0^2\\\to
10x_0-x_0^2=9-x_0^2\\\to
x_0=\frac9{10}\to y_0=\sqrt{\frac{819}{100}}.$$

Thus the two tangent lines passing through $(10, 0)$ are
$$\pm\frac9{10}\sqrt{\frac{100}{819}}\left(x-\frac9{10}\right)=y\pm\sqrt\frac{819}{100}.$$

Comment: The equations of the tangents at $(\pm3,0)$ cannot be expressed in the form you’re using. This doesn’t matter in this particular case, but what if the point through which the tangents must pass were $(3,3)$ instead?

Comment: @amd In the case of an undefined slope, one of the $x$ or $y$ values would have to be the same as the points on the circle with horizontal or vertical tangents. It would make the work I did unnecessary.

Comment: My point is that your approach doesn’t handle these cases—there’s only one solution to the system of equations then—and requires them to be dealt with separately, but a simple change of the first equation to $y_0(y-y_0)+x_0(x-x_0)=0$ covers vertical tangents, too.

Comment: @amd My approach was specifically for this problem, not a catch-all. If it had been the tangent of an ellipse, I would have used different equations too.

Answer (score 0):

There are simple 'tangency conditions' for ellipses in a standard form. Michael Rozenberg uses such a condition in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2465685/11260). See [this page](http://www.nabla.hr/Z_MemoHU-029.htm) for a derivation of this tangency condition (with $c^2$ instead of $n^2$).
In this case $a^2=b^2=9$ and for the tangency points we are solving the equations
$$\begin{align}n^2=9m^2+9\\x^2+y^2=9\\m10+n=0\\mx+n=y\\\end{align}$$
The solutions for the parameters of the lines are
$$\begin{align}m_{1,2}=\pm \frac{3\sqrt{91}}{91},&&n_{1,2}=\mp \frac{30\sqrt{91}}{91}&\end{align}$$
and for the tangency points
$$\begin{align}x_{1,2}=\frac{9}{10},&&y_{1,2}=\mp \frac{3\sqrt{91}}{10}&\end{align}$$