# Finding the point of contact for circle tangent without trigonometry

Tags: geometry

Given that we know $(x_1, y_1)$ and a circle with center (0,0) and radius R.

What is the points of contact the tangents? 
( $(x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_3,y_3)$ respectively, in the Figure. )

I am think I am able to set up two equations using Pythagaros:

$x_2^2+y_2^2=R^2$

$(x_2-x_1)^2 +(y_2-y_1)^2 = x_1^2+y_1^2-R^2$

However I am not able to solve this any further.

What I would like is to get a formula on the form (as simple as possible):

$x_2/x_3$ =

$y_2/y_3$ =

As a note I think it would be fairly easy to express it using trigonometry (using sine, and tangens), but I would like to express it without using angles.

[Problem Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M2HK.png)

Comment: Virtually a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2468474/265466. You might also find https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2507739/265466 useful. In both of those, the endpoints of the chord of contact are also computed in the process.

Comment: Expand the second equation and subtract it from the first to eliminate the squared terms.

Comment: The formulas you will end up with by bashing through this algebra are not what I’d call particularly simple and it’s easy to make stupid sign errors when applying them. For my part, I’d rather solve the simpler problem of finding the endpoints of the chord of contact with the external point on the positive $x$-axis, and then rotate that solution into place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary of results:
If
$c^2 = (x_1^2+y_1^2)/R^2$
then
$x=\dfrac{x_1\pm y_1\sqrt{c^2-1}}{c^2}$
and
$y=\dfrac{y_1\mp x_1\sqrt{c^2-1}}{c^2}$.

Suppose
$(x_2, y_2)$
is a point on the circle,
so
$x_2^2+y^2_2 = R^2$.
The line from
$(x_1, y_1)$
to
$(x_2, y_2)$
is
$\dfrac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}
=\dfrac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}
$
or
$(y-y_1)dx = (x-x_1)dy$
where
$dx =  x_2-x_1$
and
$dy =  y_2-y_1$.

The slope of this line is
$\dfrac{dy}{dx}$.

The slope of the line from
$(0, 0)$
to
$(x_2, y_2)$
is
$\dfrac{y_2}{x_2}$.

For the line to be a tangent,
the product of these slopes
must be $-1$,
so that
$-1
=\dfrac{y_2}{x_2}\dfrac{dy}{dx}
$
or
$(y_2-y_1)y_2
=-(x_2-x_1)x_2
$
so
$y_2^2+x_2^2
=y_1y_2+x_1x_2
$.

Since
$y_2^2+x_2^2 = R^2$,
$R^2
=y_1y_2+x_1x_2
$.

Removing the
"$_2$",
the equations are
$x^2+y^2 = R^2$
and
$xx_1+yy_1 = R^2$.
from the second,
$y = (R^2-xx_1)/y_1$.
Substituting in the first,

$\begin{array}\\
x^2
&=R^2-y^2\\
&=R^2-((R^2-xx_1)/y_1)^2\\
\text{or}\\
x^2y_1^2
&=y_1^2R^2-(R^2-xx_1)^2\\
&=y_1^2R^2-(R^4-2xx_1R^2+x^2x_1^2)\\
&=y_1^2R^2-R^4+2xx_1R^2-x^2x_1^2\\
\end{array}
$

so
$0
=x^2(y_1^2+x_1^2)-2xx_1R^2+R^4-y_1^2R^2
=dx^2-2xx_1R^2+R^4-y_1^2R^2
$
where
$d=y_1^2+x_1^2$.

Solving,

$\begin{array}\\
x
&=\dfrac{2x_1R^2\pm\sqrt{4x_1^2R^4-4d(R^4-y_1^2R^2)}}{2d}\\
&=\dfrac{x_1R^2\pm R\sqrt{x_1^2R^2-d(R^2-y_1^2)}}{d}\\
&=\dfrac{x_1R^2\pm R\sqrt{x_1^2R^2-dR^2+dy_1^2)}}{d}\\
&=\dfrac{x_1R^2\pm R\sqrt{(x_1^2-d)R^2+dy_1^2)}}{d}\\
&=R\dfrac{x_1R\pm\sqrt{-y_1^2R^2+dy_1^2)}}{d}\\
&=R\dfrac{x_1R\pm\sqrt{y_1^2(x_1^2+y_1^2-R^2)}}{x_1^2+y_1^2}\\
&=R\dfrac{x_1R\pm\sqrt{y_1^2(c^2R^2-R^2)}}{c^2R^2}
\qquad\text{where }c^2 = (x_1^2+y_1^2)/R^2\\
&=\dfrac{x_1\pm\sqrt{y_1^2(c^2-1)}}{c^2}\\
&=\dfrac{x_1\pm y_1\sqrt{c^2-1}}{c^2}\\
\text{and}\\
y
&=(R^2-xx_1)/y_1\\
&=((x_1^2+y_1^2)/c^2-(\dfrac{x_1\pm y_1\sqrt{c^2-1}}{c^2})x_1)/y_1\\
&=\dfrac{x_1^2+y_1^2-x_1^2\mp x_1y_1\sqrt{c^2-1}}{c^2y_1}\\
&=\dfrac{y_1^2\mp x_1y_1\sqrt{c^2-1}}{c^2y_1}\\
&=\dfrac{y_1\mp x_1\sqrt{c^2-1}}{c^2}\\
\end{array}
$

As a check,
if
$(x_1, y_1)$
is on the circle
so that $c^2 = 1$,
then
$x=x_1
$
and
$y=y_1
$
which is comforting.

Note:
I found dimensional analysis
(making sure that
the exponent of length matched)
very useful in
checking my algebra
as I went along.

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I was looking for!. Thanks for a nice stepwise solution as well. Making the product of the slopes equal -1 was really what I needed.

Only small  comment is that maybe I would flip one of the pluss-minus signs in either x or y, since it seems to me that we need to do the opposites in the two Equations.

Comment: I think you are right. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Following your idea we have that the distance $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$ form the center is

- $D_0^2=x_1^2+y_1^2$

and thus the distance $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$ form $P_2=(x_2,y_2)$ is

- $D^2=(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=D_0^2-R^2$

therefore the solution is given by the system

- $(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2=D_0^2-R^2$
- $x^2+y^2=R^2$

Answer (score 0):

Calling

$$
L\to p=p_1+\lambda \vec v\\
C\to||p-p_0|| = R
$$

then $C \cap L\to ||p_1-p_0+\lambda\vec v||^2 = R^2$ or

$$
||p_1-p_0||^2+2\lambda <p_1-p_0,\vec v> +\lambda^2||\vec v||^2 = R^2
$$

now solving for $lambda$

$$
\lambda = \frac{-2<p_1-p_0,\vec v > \pm \sqrt{4< p_1-p_0,\vec v>^2-4||\vec v||^2(||p_1-p_0||^2-R^2)}}{2||\vec v||^2}
$$

but we need tangency hence

$$
4< p_1-p_0,\vec v>^2-4||\vec v||^2(||p_1-p_0||^2-R^2)=0
$$

now calling $m = \frac{v_y}{v_x}$ and considering $p_0 = (0,0)$

$$
< p_1,\vec v>^2-||\vec v||^2(||p_1||^2-R^2)=0
$$

or

$$
(m x_1+y_1)^2-(m^2+1)(x_1^2+y_1^2-R^2) = 0
$$

or

$$
m =\frac{- x_1 y_1 \pm R\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2-R^2}}{R^2-y_1^2} = \frac{y_t-y_1}{x_t-x_1}
$$

where $(x_t, y_t)$ is one of the tangent points.

Answer (score 0):

As a second answer,
here's what trigonometry 
can do for you.
To be completely trigish,
specify the point by
angle $v$ and distance $d$
so it is at
$(d\cos(v), d\sin(v))$.

If the circle
has radius $r$,
let a point on the circle be
$(r\cos(t), r\sin(t))
=(rc, rs)$.

Since the slope
of the line
from the center
to this point is 
$\tan(t)
=\frac{s}{c}$,
the slope of the normal is
$-\frac{c}{s}$.

The equation of the normal is thus
$\dfrac{y-rs}{x-rc}
=-\dfrac{c}{s}
$
so that
$0
= s(y-rs)+c(x-rc)
= sy-s^2r+cx-c^2r
=sy+cx-r
$
or
$r
=sy+cx
=\sin(t)d\sin(v)+\cos(t)d\cos(v)
$
or
$r/d
=\sin(t)\sin(v)+\cos(t)\cos(v)
=\cos(t-v)
$
so
$t-v
=\arccos(\frac{r}{d})
$
and,
finally
$t
=v+\arccos(\frac{r}{d})
$.

To get the point,
let
$w = \frac{r}{d}$.
then
$t = v+\arccos(w)
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\cos(t)
&=\cos(v+\arccos(w))\\
&=\cos(v)\cos(\arccos(w))-\sin(v)\sin(\arccos(w))\\
&=\cos(v)w-\sin(v)\sqrt{1-w^2}\\
\end{array}
$

and similarly for $\sin(t)$.